# Gif generated in Rust and sent to mms through twilio will not play on android phone

Tags: android, rust, twilio, gif, animated-gif

Okay I have an esoteric question that spans a lot of tech. I am generating a gif programmatically (in rust) and sending that over twilio mms. The gif reaches my android Galaxy A42 phone, but the gif won't play. It just hangs on the first frame, where as most gifs would play inline in the text message thread. Not only that, but when I click to open it, it shows me a gray background with a white exclamation mark icon.

[Here's a link to the twilio media resorce that you can see plays fine.](https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/media.twiliocdn.com/ACc8f0c0682ea9fa7327edf9e45bce3792/e9aece2e18224a177605dc8580472b91)

And here's an image of the grey screen with white exclamation mark:
[image: screenshot]

I can also include the rust code... but I'm not sure if that would help yet. I'm wondering if anyone knows why some gifs won't play/open in mms messaging? The fun thing is too, when I view the image in many other clients, like my android gmail app, google photos, the gif plays fine.

Comment: What if you save the gif, then send it back to yourself (somehow)? I also noticed the twilio link doesn't have a .gif extension. This is fine in browsers since it has a mime type, but might be a problem in MMS (not sure if those have mime).

Comment: But don't you think twilio who has a massive business built on sms messaging wouldn't have their media saved in a way that can't be viewed in mms messaging? Plus there are other examples of twilio sending gifs in this way: https://www.twilio.com/blog/send-daily-animated-gifs-using-firebase-giphy-node-js-and-twilio-mms-html?category=customer-highlights

I should also mention I am saving the gif to an azure storage account first.

Comment: Seems pretty much like a question for twilio support.

Comment: yeah I was starting to reach this conclusion :) @cafce25